# How to convert a list of strings to an array of strings in C#?

Tags: c#

I know you can use the `list.ToArray()` method to convert list to an array, but I want to be able to access the individual characters of the string after conversion. For example, if the first element of the string list is "sgoth", once I convert it to an array, I want to be able to access an individual element of the array like `myArray[0,0]` which would give me the first element of the first string. How would I accomplish this when converting from a list to an array?

Comment: You can but you should do it like `myArray[0][0]`, otherwise you have a multidimensional array which is very different than an array of arrays.

Comment: What's the problem with myArrray[0][0]?

Comment: Lists, arrays and indeed strings support (almost) exactly the same indexing, so it's not sure what your issue would be of one versus the other.

Comment: @igor You have that the wrong way around - a multidimensional array cannot be jagged, but an array of arrays can be. But for an array of strings of different lengths, it HAS to be jagged, obviously - since the strings can be different lengths.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @MatthewWatson, I used the wrong terminology.

Comment: @Russell You can't do this with a multidimensional array of chars UNLESS all the strings are the same length (or you're happy with padding out some of the rows with a special character such as `'\0'`)

Answer (score 1):

I think using jagged array would be better, but if you absolutely need to have array accessed with [,] as you decriped, you could do something following:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
List<string> ListOfStrings = new List<string>() { "Test", "QWERTY" };
string[,] ArrOfStrings = new string[ListOfStrings.Count, ListOfStrings.Max(s => s.Length)];
for(int i = 0; i < ListOfStrings.Count; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < ListOfStrings[i].Length; j++){
        ArrOfStrings[i,j] = ListOfStrings[i][j].ToString();   
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(ArrOfStrings[1,2]);
```

Comment: A `char[,]` would be better: each cell does store a character after all

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using the string indexer on each particular string in array, for example

```
var strList = new List<String>() { "foo", "boo" };

var strarr = strList.ToArray();

foreach (var str in strarr)
{
    Console.Write(str[0]);
}
```

Will print you "fb"

Or by using double indexer, for example you can access the first char of the first string like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(strarr[0][0]);
```

Will just print you "f"

Answer (score 1):

> How would I accomplish this when converting from a list to an array?

It's perhaps most efficient to convert nothing

You have a `List<string>`, it can be accessed in a jagged fashion `myArray[0][0]` to get the first char of the first string, but you say you want to access it in multidim fashion, like `myArray[0,0]`..

..so you can make an adapter:

```
    public class MultiDimFlavoredJagged
    {
        List<string> _x;

        public MultiDimFlavoredJagged(List<string> x)
        {
            _x = x;
        }

        public char this[int x, int y] => _x[x][y];
    }
```

Now you can:

```
var j = new MultiDimFlavoredJagged(myArray);

var firstCharOfFirstString = j[0,0];
```

Answer (score 0):

//See example below;-

//Create a new list

List MyList = new List();

```
        //add elements to the list
        MyList.Add("Ade");
        MyList.Add("Raphael");
        MyList.Add("Bayo");
        MyList.Add("Paul");

        //creation of an array from the list
        string[] MyArray = MyList.ToArray();
```

Comment: What did it gain?